# How can I make on_message event only read messages from one channel, in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

In my code, I have this on_message event for my discord bot, I have tried making it only detect messages from one channel it works but not the way I wanted.

Like now if I type anything in any channel it prints that text in console, and seems like it overwrites normal commands with ! prefix, because commands dont even work when this event is in the code.

Is there a way to make it really only read messages from one channel rather than checking messages all across the server?

Here is the event:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("This print shows in console because this event reads every channels messages.")
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.channel.id != 1221858607000326186:
        return

    if 'vouch' in message.content.lower() and message.mentions:
        check_db_connection()
        mentioned_user = message.mentions[0]

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM midman_information WHERE midman_user LIKE %s", (f"%<@{mentioned_user.id}>%",))
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result:
            vouch_count = result[2] + 1
            cursor.execute("UPDATE midman_information SET vouch_count = %s WHERE midman_user = %s", (vouch_count, result[1]))
            db_config.commit()

            log_channel = bot.get_channel(1221858628173041674)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Vouch Logged",
                                  description=f"{message.author.mention} has given a vouch to {mentioned_user.mention} | `{vouch_count}` vouches",
                                  color=0x2b2d31)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
            embed.set_footer(text="Lunar Services")
            await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await message.delete()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that

> @bot.event async def on_message(message):

is just a wrapper for discord's [api gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#receive-events) [message create event](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#message-create) which is always sent by discord when a message in any of the servers that the bot is in is sent, so the only way to only read messages from one channel is what you have done:

```
 if message.channel.id != 1221858607000326186:
    return
```

So, no, there's no way other than check the message channel id.

Comment: Well yeh but as I said, my bot commands doesn't for some reason work when this event is part of the code, any idea what could cause this? My slash commands works normally but not the ones with ! prefix.